# Are all non-abelian groups not simple?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, simple-groups

We know that for all $n\geq 3$ the group $S_n$ is non-abelian.  We also know that for all $n\geq 3,$ the group $S_n$ is not simple, because $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ which is not trivial.

> Can we conclude that all non-abelian groups are not simple?

Comment: Why would we be able to conclude that?

Comment: There are **more** non-abelian groups than $S_n$!

Comment: You should google "simple group" before posting. There you find $A_n$ for $n\ge 5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, we cannot. For instance, $A_n$ is simple and non-abelian for each $n\geqslant5$.